# Is there way to use WMS store from geoserver but before each request SQL query database for permission reasons

Tags: sql, permissions, geoserver, wms

I have:

1. OpenLayers
2. Geoserver
3. Database
4. WMS spatial data service

WMS data is located in third party spatial service (4) away from database (3). I want to query my database before forwarding WMS request to that spatial service.

Permission checking would basically verify what data given user session is allowed to fetch.

After permission checking WMS data would be filtered according to db query results.

Can this be done with Geoserver and how or is there need for separate proxy? (I know it is possible to do SQL view for geometry that exists in DB, but what about in this situation when geometry is on other location.)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a little unclear but it sounds like something that the [GeoFence extension](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/geofence/index.html)  is designed for, it works with an internal or external install of [GeoFence](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/geofence-server/index.html#community-geofence-server).

> GeoFence offers an alternative to the GeoServer Security subsystem of GeoServer, allowing far more advanced security configurations, such as rules that combine data and service restrictions. It uses a client-server model, and this plugin only provides the client component. It must connect either to an external Geofence server, or be used in combination with the GeoServer integrated Geofence server Geofence Internal Server.